# parsing several fields of a csv with gawk on solaris

Tags: solaris, csv, gawk

I have a generated csv that has the following format:

```
unixtime;host_name;ip_adress;description;2;0;1
```

I have been trying to parse this csv to do the following:

change field 1 from unix timestamp to human readable.

change field 5 from 2 to Critical

change field 6 and 7 like this:

if the value is 0 replace by NO, if it is 1 replace by yes

I have managed to do the first 2 using this:

```
cat test.csv |
  /opt/csw/bin/gawk -F";" '{OFS=";"; $1=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $1); print $0}' |
  /opt/csw/bin/gawk -F";" '{OFS=";"; gsub("2", "CRITICAL", $5)}1'
```

but how do I to change the 1 by yes and the 0 by no in the fields $6 and $7?

If I try something like this it replaces everywhere it find a 0:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=";"} {if ($6== "0") gsub ($6,"NO"); print }' sample.csv
```

For the record, I am using Solaris and installed gawk from opencsw.

Comment: If your awk allows it, change your `gsub ($6,"NO")` to `$6="NO"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `gawk` program should work for you:

```
echo -e "unixtime;host_name;ip_adress;description;2;0;1\n1234567890;hName;hIP;hDesc;2;1;0" |
gawk -F";" 'BEGIN {OFS=";"} {
  if (NR<2) next;
  $1=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $1);
  $5=($5==2?"CRITICAL":$5);
  $6=($6?"Yes":"No") ; $7=($7?"Yes":"No") ;
  print}'

2009-02-14 00:31:30;hName;hIP;hDesc;CRITICAL;Yes;No
```

The main thing here is that you can put several commands in one `awk` call.

`$6=($6?"Yes":"No")` or, more formally `(condition?consequence:alternative)`, is called the "ternary" operator, and it is a shorthand for `if (condition) consequence else alternative`

If you want to print the header line *unchanged*, not "skip it", you can write `if (NR<2) {print;next} ;`

Edit: Implemented performance improvement hint from @cas to move the OFS assignment into a BEGIN block.

Comment: this seems to work.. now in order to give the average joe more insight. I would like to add a header but then gawk needs to be adapted to skip the first line. I know that setting NR >2 would do the trick but where I would put it?

Comment: +1 but i'd put the `OFS=";";` in a `BEGIN {}` block.  It only needs to be set at the start of the script, no need to run it for every input line.

Comment: this is what I did:
`/opt/csw/bin/gawk -F";" 'BEGIN {OFS=";"; print "last_state_change;host_name;host_address;description;state;acknowledged;notifications_enabled;comments_with_info"}
  {$1=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $1);
  $5=($5==2?"CRITICAL":$5);
  $6=($6?"Yes":"No") ; $7=($7?"Yes":"No") ;
  print $0}' `

Comment: @user2653557 Looks correct at first glance. Are you still having problems?